# d3.js v7 - scaleOrdinal - Color child nodes same as parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I was using the following functions in d3 v3.5 to colour the child nodes the same as the parent as set in scaleOrdinal().

However, this doesn't appear to work in d3 v7.

```
const colourScale = d3.scaleOrdinal()
.domain( [ "Parent", "Child 1", "Child 2" ] )
.range( [ "#abacab", "#b67a4e", "#5a6fbb" ] );
```

...

```
 function findParent(datum) {
      if (datum.depth < 2) {
        return datum.name
      } else {
        return findParent(datum.parent)
      }
    }
    
    function findParentLinks(datum) {
      if (datum.target.depth < 2) {
        return datum.target.name
      } else {
        return findParent(datum.target.parent)
      }
    }
```

and application:

```
nodeUpdate.select('circle.node')
        .attr('r', 10)
        .style("fill", function(d) {
            return colourScale(findParent(d));
        });
```

Any ideas on fixing this?  See [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lfbvh5kq/3//)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `name` property is in the `data` object, which is created by the tree generator:

```
function findParent(datum) {
  if (datum.depth < 2) {
    return datum.data.name
  } else {
    return findParent(datum.parent)
  }
}
```

Here's your code with that change:

```js
var treeData = {
  "name": "Top Level",
  "children": [{
      "name": "Child 1",
      "children": [{
          "name": "Son of Child 1"
        },
        {
          "name": "Daughter of Child 1"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Child 2"
    }
  ]
};

// Set the dimensions and margins of the diagram
var margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 90,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 90
  },
  width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// append the svg object to the body of the page
// appends a 'group' element to 'svg'
// moves the 'group' element to the top left margin
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" +
    margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var i = 0,
  duration = 750,
  root;

// declares a tree layout and assigns the size
var treemap = d3.tree().size([height, width]);

// Assigns parent, children, height, depth
root = d3.hierarchy(treeData, function(d) {
  return d.children;
});
root.x0 = height / 2;
root.y0 = 0;

// Collapse after the second level
root.children.forEach(collapse);

update(root);

// Collapse the node and all it's children
function collapse(d) {
  if (d.children) {
    d._children = d.children
    d._children.forEach(collapse)
    d.children = null
  }
}

function findParent(datum) {
  if (datum.depth < 2) {
    return datum.data.name
  } else {
    return findParent(datum.parent)
  }
}

function findParentLinks(datum) {
  if (datum.target.depth < 2) {
    return datum.target.name
  } else {
    return findParent(datum.target.parent)
  }
}

function update(source) {

  const colourScale = d3.scaleOrdinal()
    .domain(["Parent", "Child 1", "Child 2"])
    .range(["#abacab", "#b67a4e", "#5a6fbb"]);

  // Assigns the x and y position for the nodes
  var treeData = treemap(root);

  // Compute the new tree layout.
  var nodes = treeData.descendants(),
    links = treeData.descendants().slice(1);

  // Normalize for fixed-depth.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    d.y = d.depth * 180
  });

  // ****************** Nodes section ***************************

  // Update the nodes...
  var node = svg.selectAll('g.node')
    .data(nodes, function(d) {
      return d.id || (d.id = ++i);
    });

  // Enter any new modes at the parent's previous position.
  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append('g')
    .attr('class', 'node')
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")";
    })
    .on('click', click);

  // Add Circle for the nodes
  nodeEnter.append('circle')
    .attr('class', 'node')
    .attr('r', 1e-6)
    .style("fill", function(d) {
      return colourScale(findParent(d))
    });

  // Add labels for the nodes
  nodeEnter.append('text')
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .attr("x", function(d) {
      return d.children || d._children ? -13 : 13;
    })
    .attr("text-anchor", function(d) {
      return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start";
    })
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.data.name;
    });

  // UPDATE
  var nodeUpdate = nodeEnter.merge(node);

  // Transition to the proper position for the node
  nodeUpdate.transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")";
    });

  // Update the node attributes and style
  nodeUpdate.select('circle.node')
    .attr('r', 10)
    .style("fill", function(d) {
      return colourScale(findParent(d));
    });


  // Remove any exiting nodes
  var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")";
    })
    .remove();

  // On exit reduce the node circles size to 0
  nodeExit.select('circle')
    .attr('r', 1e-6);

  // On exit reduce the opacity of text labels
  nodeExit.select('text')
    .style('fill-opacity', 1e-6);

  // ****************** links section ***************************

  // Update the links...
  var link = svg.selectAll('path.link')
    .data(links, function(d) {
      return d.id;
    });

  // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
  var linkEnter = link.enter().insert('path', "g")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .attr('d', function(d) {
      var o = {
        x: source.x0,
        y: source.y0
      }
      return diagonal(o, o)
    });

  // UPDATE
  var linkUpdate = linkEnter.merge(link);

  // Transition back to the parent element position
  linkUpdate.transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr('d', function(d) {
      return diagonal(d, d.parent)
    });

  // Remove any exiting links
  var linkExit = link.exit().transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr('d', function(d) {
      var o = {
        x: source.x,
        y: source.y
      }
      return diagonal(o, o)
    })
    .remove();

  // Store the old positions for transition.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    d.x0 = d.x;
    d.y0 = d.y;
  });

  // Creates a curved (diagonal) path from parent to the child nodes
  function diagonal(s, d) {

    path = `M ${s.y} ${s.x}
            C ${(s.y + d.y) / 2} ${s.x},
              ${(s.y + d.y) / 2} ${d.x},
              ${d.y} ${d.x}`

    return path
  }

  // Toggle children on click.
  function click(event, d) {
    if (d.children) {
      d._children = d.children;
      d.children = null;
    } else {
      d.children = d._children;
      d._children = null;
    }
    update(d);
  }
}
```

```css
.node circle {
  fill: #fff;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 3px;
}

.node text {
  font: 12px sans-serif;
}

.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #ccc;
  stroke-width: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thinks links are also not now getting their parent links colours.  New question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68436845/d3-js-v7-scaleordinal-color-child-links-same-as-parent